# Expressjs set cookies in middleware

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I have a small issue.

I'm using MaxMind to get the Country of User and I'm storing the country in a cookie in this way:

```
exports.countryCookie = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.cookies.country === undefined) {
    var ip = (req.header('X-Forwarded-For') || req.connection.remoteAddress).toString();
    if (ip !== undefined) {
        satelize.satelize({ip: ip}, function(err, geoData) {
          if (err) return next();
          res.cookie('country', geoData.country);
          next();
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

my HomeController:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    var country = req.cookies.country;

    console.log(country);

    if (country !== undefined) {
      // do something...
    } else {
      // do something else...
    }
}
```

Routing:

```
app.get('/', myMiddleware.countryCookie, HomeController.index);
```

The problem is:

At the first loading the `console.log(country)` is `undefined` but the Cookie is set on the browser...

On refresh it is not anymore `undefined`.
How can I read the cookie from the homeController at the first load of the page?

It seems like the middleware is fired together with the homeController and it miss the cookie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do `req.cookies.country = geoData.country;` before calling `next()`.

Comment: Well, it works. But... Can I know why it works? Even if I remove the `res.cookie('country', ...);` it works without saving the cookie... maybe I'm missing something very important about Express... Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: It works because that's what your index controller is looking for.

Comment: ok... but res.cookie should set a cookie and req.cookies should get that cookie... Following your solution it looks like I can set a cookie using req.cookie just like to set a global variable and use it everywhere without get any data from the browser cookie...

Comment: `res.cookie()` merely sets the outgoing `Set-Cookie` header. `req.cookies` doesn't pick up those set cookies until the client makes the next request.